# Footnotes in math mode with references

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, multline

I use footnotes in the `multline` environment to explain some equality signs, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

...

\begin{multline*}
... \lim_{n\to\infty} t(n) \cdot \frac{\ln n}{n} =\footnotemark[6] \lim_{n\to\infty} (t(n) - 1) \cdot \frac{\ln n}{n} = ...
\end{multline*}
\footnotetext[6]{ Because $\frac{\ln n}{n} \to 0$, $n \to \infty$}

...

\end{document}
```

I also use package `hyperref` to add clickable references to many things, including footnotes.

The problem is that `hyperref` works just fine with usual `\footnote` command, but it does not work with the `\footnotemark`-`\footnotetext` pair.

Is there a way to make `hyperref` render clickable references for footnotes in math mode as well?

p.s.: I know that `\footnote` works with `equation` environment, but in many cases my equations are way too long for one line.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a _complete_ and _self contained_ example. It means that if we can copy paste the code, it would run _and_ your problem would reveal it self! i.e. it should include a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and the minimal amount of packages required. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman, I extended the example at your request

Comment: Do you get an error? I don't get any errors?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman, I do not get any errors.

The problem is that I also don't get a clickable reference. Try writing `foo\footnote{bar}` outside the `multline` and you will get a clickable reference near `foo` that links to `bar`. I want the same to appear in `multline`, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperref does some magic when you reference counters. However when you use the optional arguments (the `[6]` in `\footnotemark[6]`) then you're not referencing a counter, and this is not taken into consideration. One possible quick fix is to set the footnote counter before using `\footnotemark`:

```
\setcounter{footnote}{5}
\footnotemark %<- is now 6
```

Another hacky fix would be to change the behaviour so that it uses the counter when the optional arguments are passed, like so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnotemark[#1]{%
    \begingroup
    \c@footnote #1\relax
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}%
    \endgroup
    \@footnotemark}
\def\@xfootnotenext[#1]{%
    \begingroup
    \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
    \endgroup
    \@footnotetext
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    Normal footnote \footnote{frst}. Footnote with custom number (that you can click)\footnotemark[3]
    \footnotetext[3]{When you clicked, you got here!} % Footnote counter is now 3 and;
    This will now be footnote number two\footnote{This is footnote 2.}

    \begin{multline*}
        ... \lim_{n\to\infty} t(n) \cdot \frac{\ln n}{n} =\footnotemark[6] \lim_{n\to\infty} (t(n) - 1) \cdot \frac{\ln n}{n} = ...
    \end{multline*}
    \footnotetext[6]{ Because $\frac{\ln n}{n} \to 0$, $n \to \infty$}
\end{document}
```

NB: The order of the footnotes here will be the order of which they are given in the document.

Comment: gotcha. Actually, I only needed to use `[6]` because I had two such foonotes in one equation, so using `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}` before first `\footnotetext` would solve my problem as well.